# HTML buttons on the same line

Tags: css, html

I have this html code which made in browser three buttons.How can I put the buttons on the same line?(they appear on different lines).

```
    <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/home.html"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Home" />

</form>


     <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/players.html"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Players" />

 </form>

 <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/league.html"/>
    <input type="submit" value="League" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
input[type=submit]{cursor:pointer}
form input{float:left;margin:5px}
```

```html
    <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/home.html"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Home" />

</form>
     
     
     <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/players.html"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Players" />

 </form>

 <form action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/league.html"/>
    <input type="submit" value="League" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code

```
<style>
    form { display : inline-block; } 
</style>
```

Comment: I add this and nothing happens :(

Comment: where did you add ? hope you have added after </head> and before <body>

Comment: @Foreastbtch ohh dear, you have not completed </html>. Put </body> and </html> at the last.

Comment: ohh my bad. check <style> tag.

Comment: i put this in css file (style.css).What do you mean with <style> tag?

Comment: so can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

form tag's default display value is block. If you make it inline-block, it will solve that problem.

```html
<form style="display: inline-block;" action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/home.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Home" />
</form>
<form style="display: inline-block;" action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/players.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Players" />
</form>
<form style="display: inline-block;" action="file:///C:/Users/andre/Desktop/league.html">
  <input type="submit" value="League" />
</form>
```